# Create a group variable when number of rows is not a multiple of number of groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame of many companies (let's say 7 companies) and many periods (let's say 2 periods). I need to create a new column by dividing each period's company into few parts (let's say 3 parts). Now since 7 can not exactly be divided by 3, I want assign two rows to each of the first groups, and one extra row to the last group. In the following table, the 'res' column is the expected result:

```
Company     Period   res
1              1      11
2              1      11
3              1      12
4              1      12
5              1      13
6              1      13
7              1      13
1              2      21
2              2      21
3              2      22
4              2      22
5              2      23
6              2      23
7              2      23
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not make much sense at the moment, What do you mean by 'dividing into three parts'?  You are merging companies 1 and 2, 3 and 4, and 5 to 7. The first digit of your output appears to be the period, and the second the merged company. Is that true? Will it always be 7 companies and three merged results? The logic you are applying is not at all clear.

Comment: It is important when you create portfolios. Say we analyze 84 companies of a country and we want to make 10 equal portfolios each period ( meaning we have to split all companies into 10 groups according to some basis). Now since 84 companies are not exactly divided into 10 groups, we can create 10 portfolios by keeping 8 firms in every 9 portfolios and rest of the 12 firms in last 10th portfolio. Hope you understand. @StewartRoss

Comment: On your example above you have 3 groups (2, 2, 3). Considering that you want the last to be 3, is it acceptable for the groups to be, say, (1, 3, 3) or (3, 1, 3)? - but last will always be 3

Comment: More explicitly, say I already sorted companies by the volatility of return. Means top companies are highly volatile and bottoms are less. Hence I divide those firms into groups on the basis of High volatile to Low volatile and examine the performance of each group by analyzing other variables. Means I want to check whether high volatile companies have performance deviation than low volatile companies or not. @StewartRoss

Comment: nvm I got. I ll give it a shot

Comment: That is not the typical way how finance researchers create portfolios. Normally they keep equal firms in each portfolio. If one or two extra firm remains they just add in the last portfolio. When we have a lot of firms in our sample that one or two extra firms in the last portfolio do not put any impact on average performance. @Sotos

Comment: What is the maximum number of periods? What is the maximum number of portfolios? This is important, as your example is 7 companies and 3 periods in which case your combined column is 11..13 through 31..33. As there is no separator between the period and the company this type of  combination in which digits are combined without explicit separation will fail if the number of companies or the number of periods grows large, and you have not been explicit about what the actual ranges will be.  For instance, 112 could be read as period 1 portfolio 12, or period 11 portfolio 2.

Comment: I posted an answer. Have a look and let me know

Comment: Well, in that case, I can put the name of the companies. Say A, B, C, D,  AA, AB etc. However, in my case, it was 84 companies and 221 periods. I may be higher for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you want to divide into equal parts and put the remaining (in case there is a remainder) in the last group. The following function does that, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x, parts){
  len1 <- length(x)
  i1 <- len1 %% parts
  v1 <- rep((len1 - i1)/parts, parts)
  v1[length(v1)] <- v1[length(v1)] + i1
  v2 <- rep(seq_along(v1), v1)
  return(v2)
}

#Here are some trials,

f1(seq(7), 3)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
f1(seq(8), 3)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
f1(seq(9), 3)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
f1(seq(10), 3)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Now you need to apply it in each group using the split-apply method (using `data.table` or `dplyr` will definitely speed up this process), i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(split(df, df$Period), function(i) {
      i$New_column <- paste0(i$Period, f1(i$Company, 3)); i}))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      Company Period New_column
> 1.1        1      1         11
> 1.2        2      1         11
> 1.3        3      1         12
> 1.4        4      1         12
> 1.5        5      1         13
> 1.6        6      1         13
> 1.7        7      1         13
> 2.8        1      2         21
> 2.9        2      2         21
> 2.10       3      2         22
> 2.11       4      2         22
> 2.12       5      2         23
> 2.13       6      2         23
> 2.14       7      2         23
> ```

**NOTE:** You can easily add a separator in `paste0` to distinguish between `1_11` and `11_1`

Comment: when I ran first f1 codes it shows error : object 'v2' not found@sotos

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Run it like the trials first, `f1(seq(10), 4)`

Comment: Sorry, I am disturbing you again. Is it possible to make the column like 1_1, 1_1......, 1_2,1_2, ...... The reason is in case of big numbers of periods, it is difficult to identify which one is an indicator of a month and which one is the indicator of a group (portfolio).   Or any other way of representation you think better. @Sotos

Comment: Just add the delimeter of choice is `paste0(i$Period, '_', f1( ...))`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function of number of companies (`nc`) and number of groups (`nc`). For all but the last group (`ng - 1`), the length of each group is the quotient (`nc %/% ng`). For the last group, the length is the quotient plus the remainder (`nc %% ng`).

```
f <- function(nc, ng){
  qu <- nc %/% ng
  rep(1:ng, c(rep(qu, ng - 1), qu + nc %% ng))
}
```

Do this for each period:

```
d$res2 <- ave(d$Period, d$Period, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, "_", f(7, 3)))    
d
#    Company Period res res2
# 1        1      1  11  1_1
# 2        2      1  11  1_1
# 3        3      1  12  1_2
# 4        4      1  12  1_2
# 5        5      1  13  1_3
# 6        6      1  13  1_3
# 7        7      1  13  1_3
# 8        1      2  21  2_1
# 9        2      2  21  2_1
# 10       3      2  22  2_2
# 11       4      2  22  2_2
# 12       5      2  23  2_3
# 13       6      2  23  2_3
# 14       7      2  23  2_3
```

Here the number of companies is hard coded (`7`), but this could of course be calculated from your data.

---

If the remainder doesn't *have* to be allocated to the last group, you may just use `cut`:

```
ave(d$Company, d$Period, FUN = function(x) cut(seq_along(x), 3))
```

Comment: We can also use `parallel::splitIndices`